# In jQuery how can you attached change events to regular objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can you bind a change (or add/remove) event to a object or collection of objects to see see if it has changed using jQuery. I have looked around but can't seem to find much on the subject, yet it seems like a fairly standard use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event handler for any event you like to any element you like, but it will only be called if the event actually is triggered. As there is no change event defined for anything other than form fields, nothing will happen unless you trigger the event yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As Guffa pointed out, there is no change event in regular object, but input, textarea, and select. So you have to make your own content-change event. This article has how-to. http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/ Read the last part.